# Will Android Wear receive PutDataRequest if GoogleApiClient returns connected?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os

I have a wear application and a phone application that talks to each other. The phone application pushes data to the wear.

On the phone, GoogleApiClient.isConnected() is returning true even though the bluetooth is off. This suggests that we aren't necessarily connecting to the wear but to a Google service responsible for syncing the data.

However when I then connect the wear(watch) afterwards the data is never received by the watch. Is there a delay in the data sync between wear and the phone application? Does anyone have any information on this?

Comment: Does your Wear app receive the data if it is connected when you call `putDataItem()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when reconnected, Android Wear will sync all data items between devices. As this process happens with all Wear apps and the Bluetooth protocol used is relatively low bandwidth, this can take a while to happen on your specific app (usually still less than a minute if that - depends on the amount of data being synced).

Make sure your app can communicate across the data layer when attached to one another. If you are using a [WearableListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html), you should be able to get a good idea this delay by noting when the device reconnects (via [onPeerConnected()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html#onPeerConnected(com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node))) and measure the time until [onDataChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html#onDataChanged(com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEventBuffer)) is called, although there really isn't much you can do besides sync less data.

Comment: When testing i was not able to get the function onDataChanged() to trigger if the device and phone were dis-connected at the time the message was sent. Seems like the message was simply lost and I waited for a few minutes.

Comment: However as you answered all the data did eventually get synced and I could then access it via the call Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems(googleApiClient).await(), which returned a iterable list of DataItems.